# Error using rake db:create with postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, postgresql, web-applications

I get this error, I have been trying to switch from sqlite3 to postgres. This error has been a thorn in my side. I am not quite sure how to fix it.

**Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"abc"}
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?**

I think the problem my might be in my database.yml file here it is:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: abc

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: asa

production:
  <<: *default
  database: cba
```

Here is my git if you need to see what any of the other files look like:  https://github.com/AceConcept/Todo-App

A screenshot of what happens when I try to open app
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc4v8.jpg

What exactly happens when I use 'rake db:create'

```
 bundle exec rake db:create
(in /home/ubuntu/workspace/todo)
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:88:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:102:in `block in create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:209:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:208:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:208:in `each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:101:in `create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"abc"}
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:88:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:102:in `block in create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:209:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:208:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:208:in `each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:101:in `create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"asasasasas"}
```

Comment: What happens when you run `psql` in the same directory as your project?

Comment: I get : rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'psql'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: Do you have postgres installed? If you're on a mac you should get the http://postgresapp.com/. If on linux you should use `apt-get` http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/ or the equivalent.

Comment: Will that work? I am using a cloud ide online cloud9.com

Comment: It doesn't recognize apt-get ):

Comment: Never used Cloud 9 before so not sure, maybe Google about installing PostgreSQL on it. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, i have tried that already ): Thanks for trying to help